# MailChimp and Zapier: Invalid Resource - Your merge fields were invalid. BIRTHDAY: Please enter a month (01-12) and a day (01-31)

Tags: mailchimp, zapier

I am trying to create a [Zapier](https://zapier.com) integration template for my Zapier application with [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com).

The following error is being thrown by MailChimp:

```
Invalid Resource - Your merge fields were invalid. BIRTHDAY: Please enter a month (01-12) and a day (01-31).
```

The value of the `merges__BIRTHDAY` field is `"1983-05-03"` which is an [ISO 8601](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html#date) format compliant with [Zapier's date field format guidelines](https://platform.zapier.com/partners/planning-guide#date).

What went wrong? What is the format I am supposed to be using here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [MailChimp's docs](https://mailchimp.com/help/change-a-date-field-to-a-birthday-field/) they expect a birthday in the format `"MM/DD"`. When they say *"Please enter a month (01-12) and a day (01-31)"*, they mean *only* those two values; it's the day in the year someone's birthday falls on, *not* the date of the day they were born.